# Why is "retry on failure" grayed out in the Google Cloud Functions console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm setting up some Cloud Functions to handle Firestore document events. I'm using the standard `firebase deploy --only functions` command to deploy my functions. When I follow the instructions [in this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#how_to_enable_retries), I go to the configuration for my function on the GCP console and see the checkbox I need to enable is grayed out, with no further info:

[image: cloud function trigger configuration]

Any ideas as to why I can't enable auto-retry through the GCP console? The aforementioned docs describe this approach (through the GCP console) as the only way to enable retries. Ideally I could annotate my functions code in some way that enables/disables retries per function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question... just had to click the `EDIT` button on the top toolbar to make the checkbox editable:

[image: function details toolbar]

Would still be nice to have a way to do this on deployment, either through a flag to the `firebase deploy` command, or through code annotation.

Comment: can't really have it all

Comment: you could now simply use the '--retry' flag.